# pip install traceback error while installing packages in Python

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, pip, setuptools

I'm having issues to install python packages using 'pip', i have no problems until a couple of days ago, but now suddenly I have the error below every time i want to install something.
I'm using Python 2.7 on windows, and I already reinstall 'pip' by still the same.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   
   File "C:\Python27\Scripts\pip-script.py", line 9, in <module>
   load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 339, in load_entry_point
    ns.clear()

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2470, in load_entry_point
    else:

  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2184, in load
    raise ValueError

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\vcs\mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pip\download.py", line 26, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
```

ImportError: **cannot import name IncompleteRead**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/python-pip/+bug/1306991), you likely have a bad version of requests installed. It sounds like you need to remove requests completely and any reference to it and reinstall it using something other than pip. Otherwise pip may reinstall the old version using its cache.

Comment: Thanks, i uninstall python and and the libraries and install everything again and now is working.

Comment: You may not need to uninstall python completely, just uninstall pip and reinstall it as it is shown here https://www.unixarena.com/2019/06/how-to-install-pip-on-rhel-7-centos-7.html/