# How do I fix 'ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead'?

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install anything with `pip` or `pip3`, I get:

```
$ sudo pip3 install python3-tk
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name 'IncompleteRead'
```

I have a Ubuntu 14.10 system.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318535/pip-install-traceback-error-while-installing-packages-in-python

Comment: @cel: This is not a duplicate, because it is for windows and I have already seen that.

Comment: The link in the accepted answer points to ubuntu's issue tracker - so this issue does not seem to be windows specific. Have you tried reinstalling python as `OP` suggested?

Comment: @cel Never mind, I just found a quite simple solution.

Comment: ...which was what?

Comment: @JonathanHartley Very likely the solution I accepted...

Comment: related bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=744145

Answer (score 434, accepted):

While [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27341847/2854723) might be the reason, this snipped worked for me as a solution (in `Ubuntu 14.04`):

First remove the package from the package manager:

```
# apt-get remove python-pip
```

And then install the latest version by side:

```
# easy_install pip
```

(thanks to @Aufziehvogel, @JunchaoGu)

Comment: For the interested: `--upgrade (-U)`: force upgrade (searches PyPI for latest versions)

Comment: You just have to be careful, not to confuse your native package manager (apt) by side installing through `easy_install`. If possible, I'd recommend to `apt-get remove pip` and then `easy_install pip`.

Comment: @Aufziehvogel `apt-get remove python-pip`

Comment: Great answer.  Was getting errors with `SaltStack` trying to run 'pip.installed` states, and this fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: Basically this answer makes the situation even worse.

Comment: So what will be a better solution?

Comment: just a side note: I think a more precise command to remove pip in ubuntu is "sudo apt-get remove python-pip"

Comment: For me, this was 'apt-get remove python3-pip', followed by 'apt-get install python3-setuptools', followed by 'easy_install3 pip'

Comment: for debian user, you might want to copy the pip to usr bin folder: 
cp /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin/

Comment: I had to use `sudo apt-get remove phython-pip` and then `sudo easy_install pip` on a Debian 85 VM.

Comment: There is a convention that says that a `#` characters means a privileged console, e.g. via `sudo`

Comment: This fixed it for me on Lubuntu 15.10

Comment: This is now fixed in Ubuntu 14.04, `sudo apt-get install python-pip` resolves the error.

Comment: I had to do... sudo apt-get remove python-pip, sudo apt-get update, sudo apt install python-pip. That cleared the situation up.

Comment: Still works for me using easy_install. apt-get reinstalling pip doesn't work.

Comment: in Debian after the mentioned steps did: `cp /usr/local/bin/pip /usr/bin` to get it working

Answer (score 85):

This problem is caused by a mismatch between your pip installation and your requests installation.

As of requests version 2.4.0 `requests.compat.IncompleteRead` [has been removed](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/501). Older versions of pip, e.g. [from July 2014](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/0dedf2b6f5adefcc29d3d295318a7ebc916fc822/pip/download.py), still relied on `IncompleteRead`. In the [current version](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/a47411b18acfd84947acb604c1341660c128e606/pip/download.py) of pip, the import of `IncompleteRead` has been removed.

So the one to blame is either:

- requests, for removing public API too quickly
- Ubuntu for updating pip too slowly

You can solve this issue, by either updating pip via Ubuntu (if there is a newer version) or by installing pip aside from Ubuntu.

Comment: pip install requests -U, fixed the issue.

Comment: @jonincanada how am i supposed to run a pip command when pip crashes?

Answer (score 79):

For fixing pip3 (worked on Ubuntu 14.10):

```
easy_install3 -U pip
```

Comment: This works in Ubuntu 14.04 as well. Be aware this installs a `/usr/local/bin/pip` that is for Python3; previously `pip` ran a Python 2 version. I fixed it by disabling `/usr/local/bin/pip` entirely so I have to explicitly run `pip2` or `pip3`.

Comment: on Debian `Jessie` for `python2.7` - after purging pip with `sudo apt-get purge python-requests` and reinstalling with apt-get (shown on another answer), running `easy_install -U pip` did the trick.

Comment: For myself more than anything; this is the fix that worked for me.

Comment: Works like a charm!

Answer (score 34):

Or you can remove all `requests`.

For example:

- `rm -rf /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests*`

Comment: This worked for me. May i know what is the relation of the requests to installation of python-pip

Comment: If you look to `requests` module, you will see this module/lib is use for send HTTP requests. `pip` module need `requests` module to download packages from ` Python Package Index`. And the `requests` removed by you has another version that `pip` require to be installed.

Comment: This worked for me as well; I ran into the error when running an Ansible playbook that used the `pip` module to install dependencies on a fresh/new install of Raspbian Jessie (for Raspberry Pi). After deleting the requests dist package, everything works great.

Comment: Worked for me also. I upgraded my OS from wheezy to jessie, so may have broken something. The three methods stated above did not work for me first off. However if I used method 3 and then the rm -rf command I found that it did work.

Comment: this did the job, while still keeping pip from the debian repo. thanks a lot!

Comment: Changed python version to 3.4, and this worked for me.  I did both, but deleting requests in only 2.7 didn't work.  After that, I updated pip and pip3, and removed uWSGI from pip (pip2) outside venv

Comment: Worked on raspbian jessie. Thanks!

Answer (score 23):

On Ubuntu 14.04 I resolved this by using the pip installation bootstrap script, as described in [the documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/installing.html)

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
```

That's an OK solution for a development environment.

Comment: This solves the issue. Too bad that such an issue is still open on LTS version.

Comment: I had this problem in Ubuntu 15 and it appears to be working. The get-pip.py script said I already had the package I was looking for but suggested I use sudo with the -H flag which I believe is working.

Answer (score 17):

The problem is the Python module `requests`. It can be fixed by

```
$ sudo apt-get purge python-requests
[now requests and pip gets deinstalled]
$ sudo apt-get install python-requests python-pip
```

If you have this problem with Python 3, you have to write `python3` instead of `python`.

Comment: It's absolutely a nice solution.

Comment: Cool to know about `purge`. This still didn't install a working version of pip and when i tried to run `from requests.compat import IncompleteRead` in the python CLI it gave the same error. What DID work, after running the above commands, was running `easy_install -U pip`

Comment: This is the best solution that does not involve easy_install, and doesn't bork your system by removing pip first.

Answer (score 9):

This should work for you. Follow these simple steps.

First, let's remove the pip which is already installed so it won't cause any error.

Open Terminal.

Type: **sudo apt-get remove python-pip**

It removes pip that is already installed.

**Method-1**

**Step: 1** sudo easy_install -U pip

It will install pip latest version.

And will return its address: Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-6.1.1-py2.7.egg

**or**

**Method-2**

**Step: 1** go to this [link](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).

**Step: 2** Right click >> Save as.. with name get-pip.py .

**Step: 3** use: cd to go to the same directory as your get-pip.py file

**Step: 4** use: sudo python get-pip.py

It will install pip latest version.

**or**

**Method-3**

**Step: 1** use: sudo apt-get install python-pip

It will install pip latest version.

Comment: Could you add a little  more details to your answer?

Comment: Sure. But where did you get confused?

Comment: Thanks I removed python-pip and then used easy_install.  pip is working again.

Comment: @phansen no problem (y)

Answer (score 8):

Simply running `easy_install -U pip` resolved my problem.

Comment: Commenting oldly to express my amazement that I had to wade through a thread of people apt-get purging various softwares just to find this very simple, helpful solution. Not sure what all limitations there were when the question was asked, but *this worked*.

Answer (score 5):

Check wether you have an older version of `requests` sitting in your `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and remove it if it is the case (change path to reflect your python version). This solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

My version of pip on ubuntu suggests:

```
  pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Didn't work for me as pip is totally borked by this error. Any usage (even `pip --version`) displays the `cannot import name IncompleteRead` error, so pip is sadly unable to upgrade itself

Comment: Actually this works on a clean installation of Ubuntu 14.04 (bootstrap from `minbase`). Somehow `pip` manages to update itself without referring `requests` module.

Comment: This won't work with a broken pip -- a chicken-or-egg dilemma.

Answer (score 4):

In Windows, this worked from an administrative prompt:

- Delete `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\requests*`
- `easy_install requests==2.3`
- `pip install --upgrade pip`
- `pip install --upgrade requests`

Comment: Installed/reinstalled `python-requests` and `python3-requests` which fixed pip3. Had made the mistake of installing python3.6beta then python3.6rc.

Answer (score 3):

I tried with every answer avobe, but couldn't make it.

Did this and worked

```
sudo apt-get purge python-virtualenv
sudo pip install pip -U
```

After that I just installed virtualenv with pip

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
```

I built the virtualenv that I was working on and
the package was installed easily.
Get into the virtualenv by using `source /bin/activate` 
and try to install your package, for example:

```
pip install terminado
```

It worked for me, although I was using python2.7 not python3

Answer (score 0):

Check if have a python interpreter alive in any of the terminal windows. If so kill it and try `sudo pip` which worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo apt-get remove python-pip
2. sudo easy_install requests==2.3.0
3. sudo apt-get install python-pip

Answer (score 0):

You can download recent packages manually from these pages:

- https://packages.debian.org/fr/stretch/all/python3-pip/download
- https://packages.debian.org/fr/stretch/all/python-pip-whl/download

Then, install it by running `dpkg`:

```
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

For CentOS I used this and it worked please use the following commands:

```
sudo pip uninstall requests
sudo pip uninstall urllib3
sudo yum remove python-urllib3
sudo yum remove python-requests
```

(confirm that all those libraries have been removed)

```
sudo yum install python-urllib3
sudo yum install python-requests
```