# ImportError: cannot import name ProtocolError

Tags: python, pip

Recently I was having difficulties using pip and any time I tried to issue a pip command I was receiving the below error message.

```
File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5', 'console_scripts', 'pip2.7')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 353, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2302, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2029, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import requests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/utils.py", line 25, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import charade as chardet
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 33, in <module>
    from .connection import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .util import (
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .retry import Retry
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ..exceptions import (
ImportError: cannot import name ProtocolError
```

I'm using openSUSE SLES 12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I struggled trying to find a solution to this error as everything that I searched for didn't help, that was until I eventually stumbled upon an answer to another pip related question on StackOverflow which solved my error. [How do I fix 'ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341064/how-do-i-fix-importerror-cannot-import-name-incompleteread)

So to get rid of this error message, issue the following command.

```
easy_install -U pip
```