# cannot import name 'getargspec_no_self' when running scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the package `scikit-learn`. I have successfully installed it using `conda` and `pip` functions. However when attempting to use it:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
```

I get the following error....

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-c359d56bf3d1> in <module>()
      1 ## Trying a different alternative with Stikitlearn package
      2 
----> 3 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

C:\Users\0806655a\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\__init__.py in <module>()
      8 from .hashing import FeatureHasher
      9 from .image import img_to_graph, grid_to_graph
---> 10 from . import text
     11 
     12 __all__ = ['DictVectorizer', 'image', 'img_to_graph', 'grid_to_graph', 'text',

C:\Users\0806655a\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py in <module>()
     27 from ..externals import six
     28 from ..externals.six.moves import xrange
---> 29 from ..preprocessing import normalize
     30 from .hashing import FeatureHasher
     31 from .stop_words import ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS

C:\Users\0806655a\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\__init__.py in <module>()
     29 from .label import MultiLabelBinarizer
     30 
---> 31 from .imputation import Imputer
     32 
     33 

C:\Users\0806655a\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\imputation.py in <module>()
      7 import numpy.ma as ma
      8 from scipy import sparse
----> 9 from scipy import stats
     10 
     11 from ..base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

C:\Users\0806655a\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\__init__.py in <module>()
    336 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
    337 
--> 338 from .stats import *
    339 from .distributions import *
    340 from .morestats import *

C:\Users\0806655a\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py in <module>()
    181 import scipy.linalg as linalg
    182 import numpy as np
--> 183 from . import distributions
    184 from . import mstats_basic
    185 from ._distn_infrastructure import _lazywhere

C:\Users\0806655a\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\distributions.py in <module>()
      8 from __future__ import division, print_function, absolute_import
      9 
---> 10 from ._distn_infrastructure import (entropy, rv_discrete, rv_continuous,
     11                                     rv_frozen)
     12 

C:\Users\0806655a\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\stats\_distn_infrastructure.py in <module>()
      6 
      7 from scipy._lib.six import string_types, exec_
----> 8 from scipy._lib._util import getargspec_no_self as _getargspec
      9 
     10 import sys

ImportError: cannot import name 'getargspec_no_self'
```

I cannot understand what is the `'getargspec_no_self'`. Any ideas of where to look are more than welcome.

Kind regards!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I use part of solution from this [how-do-i-fix-importerror-cannot-import-name-incompleteread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341064/how-do-i-fix-importerror-cannot-import-name-incompleteread)

On my anaconda prompt,I type 'easy-install pip' and the problem dissapear. I use Windows 7 & Python 2.7.11