# Install Wheel on Raspberry Pi 2 failing - IncompleteRead

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi2

I'm trying to install a wheel file and keep stumbling over the following error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip-3.2 install DsController-1.0-py3-none-any.whl

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip-3.2", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in 
    load_entry_point
return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in
load_entry_point
return ep.load()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
['__name__'])
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in
<module>
from pip.download import path_to_url
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name 'IncompleteRead'
```

I followed the answer in this thread: [How do I fix 'ImportError: cannot import name IncompleteRead'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341064/how-do-i-fix-importerror-cannot-import-name-incompleteread), unfortunately without success.

The Wheel can be installed without problems under Windows.

Comment: This error is pretty well explained in the thread you linked (and installing the latest version of pip is mentioned as a solution in Pi forums)... Which solution did you apply?

Comment: @PeterBrittain I tried the solution with removing and re-installing pip. It didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Which version are you now running?

Comment: Version Pip-3.2 is what I'm currently using

Comment: That's notthes version of pip.  The 3.2 here refers to the version of Python you're using.  Try `pip -V`

Comment: @PeterBrittain I'm running version 8.1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not picking up the version of `pip` that you have installed when running `pip-3.2`.

As you can see, [version 8.1.2 of download.py](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/8.1.2/pip/download.py) does not import IncompleteRead.  However, [version 1.5.6 of download.py](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/1.5.6/pip/download.py) does.

Either your copy of pip and pip-3.2 are not the same executable (and so just using pip will work), or your system has a confused import path that means you are picking up the wrong version of the pip package.  In the latter case, remvoing the old installation or fixing your import path should work.

Comment: I think I will set the whole thing again up from scratch again.