# Python import error "getfullargspec"

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

when I do:

```
from sklearn import linear_model
```

I get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'getfullargspec'
```

Interestingly, this does not happen a few days ago. So I tried to install python and scipy stack again on my computer using Anaconda again but does not solve the problem. What might be wrong with my system?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Install using pip

`pip install scipy`

And use pip to install the following packages such as numpy, pandas, etc...

If you are using Python 3 then install pip3 and use `pip3 install scipy`

Check this answer out if problem persists: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27425458/5110035