# Issue with dependencies -- ImportError: cannot import name getfullargspec

Tags: python, numpy, dependencies, point-clouds, mayavi

I'm trying to use mayavi in python to visualize a pointcloud, and cannot resolve this error. I'm sure it is an easy pip install, but I am unsure of the command. Any help is much appreciated! Thanks!

BTW, I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and have tried installing scipy as mentioned here: [Python import error "getfullargspec"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44495251/python-import-error-getfullargspec). I have also ran pip install traitsui. Additionally, I have rebooted my system.

Update:
After further digging, it appears that it may be an issue with Python versions. I was able to get it to run with Python3, but not Python 2.7 (I need it to work with python 2). I have also tried modifying the code within handler.py to `getargspec` instead of `getfullargspec`. I was given an error about trait_factory by doing this

Here is the entire printout:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mayavi_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    from mayavi import mlab
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/mlab.py", line 16, in <module>
    from mayavi.tools.camera import view, roll, yaw, pitch, move
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/camera.py", line 24, in <module>
    from .engine_manager import get_engine
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/tools/engine_manager.py", line 12, in <module>
    from mayavi.preferences.api import preference_manager
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/preferences/api.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .preference_manager import preference_manager
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mayavi/preferences/preference_manager.py", line 29, in <module>
    from traitsui.api import View, Group, Item
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitsui/api.py", line 37, in <module>
    from .editors.api import (
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitsui/editors/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from .api import (
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitsui/editors/api.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .array_editor import ArrayEditor
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitsui/editors/array_editor.py", line 34, in <module>
    from ..view import View
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitsui/view.py", line 41, in <module>
    from .ui import UI
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitsui/ui.py", line 51, in <module>
    from .handler import Handler, ViewHandler
  File "/home/user/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitsui/handler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from inspect import getfullargspec
ImportError: cannot import name getfullargspec
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution for this problem was to use older packages. Not all of the dependencies such as traitsui are compatible with Python 2.7. Even though an older version of mayavi was installed, the dependencies that are installed automatically are not compatible (they only support Python 3).

Here are the versions that work well together for me:

[mayavi==4.6.2](https://pypi.org/project/mayavi/4.6.2/)

[traitsui==6.1.3](https://pypi.org/project/traitsui/6.1.3/)

[traits==5.2.0](https://pypi.org/project/traits/5.2.0/)

[numpy==1.17.4](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.17.4/)

[pyface==6.1.2](https://pypi.org/project/pyface/6.1.2/)

To install a specific version, just run `sudo pip install packageName==#.#.#`