# Unable to fetch data from firebase on my raspberry pi

Tags: python, firebase, raspberry-pi3

This is a screenshot from my raspberry pi screen:

[image: This is a screenshot from my raspberry pi screen.]

I have fetched data from firebase using the following code in my pc. But i'm unable to do the same on my raspberry pi3. To run the same code I have tried installing python-firebase on terminal in pi but it showed the error as seen in the screenshot.

Code that worked in my pc.

```
firebase import firebase
firebase = firebase.FirebaseApplication('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/', None) result = firebase.get('/messages', None) 
print (result)
```

Comment: Please don't post screen shots of _text_ information.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27341064/1531971

Comment: pip is working for me. I have installed requests using it. sudo pip install requests==1.1.0.