# 'IncompleteRead' import error in urllib3

Tags: python, urllib3

I have recently installed urllib3, and I am getting an error that I can't find anything about online. The line causing the issue is:

```
from .packages.six.moves.http_client import (IncompleteRead as httplib_IncompleteRead)
```

This causes:

```
Import Error: cannot import name 'Incomplete Read'
```

When I run the exceptions.py file for urllib3 I get the following result:

```
SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import
```

What could possibly be the issue here?

Comment: why is the module enclosed in parentheses? Not sure if that affects anything tho..

Comment: I'm not sure but I haven't changed anything, this is how it comes with urllib3. I just reinstalled it. It should not matter I think

Comment: Was it installed via `pip`? You might want to take a [look at this question also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27341064/how-do-i-fix-importerror-cannot-import-name-incompleteread)

Comment: I did install through pip. I have taken a look at this before and I am confused by a lot of it. I use PyCharm if that makes a difference. And I have already tried deleted and reinstalling pip

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your error. Are you trying to manually run `exceptions.py`? the module should work fine as it is.

Comment: yes that is what I was trying.. I have tried now deleting and reinstalling the requests folder without using pip. still doesn't work

Comment: The strange thing is, the code works completely fine in the command line. It just doesn't work in PyCharm