# Python pip returning incomplete read error

Tags: python, pip, raspberry-pi3

quick thing: YES I KNOW THERE IS ANOTHER POST ON THIS, but its answers do NOT solve my issue.

So I installed this package called hangups on my raspberry pi. It ruined my pip installation and gave me the error below. However if you google this error, you will come to a post that does have a solution: re installing pip. I had done this several times; Once reinstalling pip from apt, 2nd time from get-pip.py, last by reinstalling python3. Irregardless, none of these methods solved my error (Oh and i also must mention that i did try the `easy_install` reinstallation of pip but that fails too). Nothing seems to work. My theory is that some repository somewhere is **not** updated because the error message points to some ancient version of pip (<= 2) (on my mac pip is at 9 running same version of python 3) and for some reason, pip has this dependency that isnt there just disables my pip binary. I would install them, but (lol) i dont have pip. The error is below. **How do I fix this?**
please comment if you need more information. Thanks!!!

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py:80: 
RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.22) or chardet (2.3.0) doesn't 
match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==1.5.6', 'console_scripts', 'pip3')()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 356, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2476, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2190, in load
    ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/vcs/mercurial.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.download import path_to_url
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 25, in <module>
    from requests.compat import IncompleteRead
ImportError: cannot import name 'IncompleteRead'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27318535/pip-install-traceback-error-while-installing-packages-in-python

Comment: yes but that leaves easy_install. How would i do that for python 3?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah ok so for future reference kids, easy_install does (like pip) have a python 3.x version. Just do `sudo easy_install3 -U pip`.